# loss versus lost in computing

Tags: word-choice, terminology

I know that loss is a noun and lost is a verb/adjective but if we lost the connection with a server, which of these two messages will be the most accurate:

- Connectivity loss with server

or

- Connection lost with server

Maybe I'm mistaken but I read the first one as losing some messages but being able to reach the server; and the second as not being able to reach the server at all.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We tend to use **loss** when the loss is not complete, as in "packet loss". We are losing some packets,  not all.  When the connection has been dropped, it's **lost**.

Your message could say any of the following:

> Connection lost to server
>
> Connection to server lost
>
> Lost connection
>
> Lost connection to server

**Connectivity** is an overarching concept, the ability to make and establish connections.

Answer (score 2):

As a programmer I would say both are correct, but I feel the second sounds slightly better and would be more common. The second one is a complete sentence, while the first one is not a complete sentence as it lacks a verb. Still, the first one is acceptable, as it is characteristic of the sort of shorthand often used in error messages in computing.

To me, these phrases don't really have a difference in meaning. In terms of the meanings of both phrases, it is possible that making a connection to the server was never possible at all, or that a connection was made but later lost.

Comment: I would not say the second phrase is a sentence. It is missing the verb.

Comment: Although *lost* can be the past tense of *lose*, in the second example it acts, not as a verb, but as an adjective describing the state of the connection. So the example requires a verb such as *was* or *has been* to make a sentence.